# Dynamically Defining Flask Route & Importing Data

Tags: python, dynamic, flask, routes

I'm getting started with Flask and honestly I've reached the bang head against desk part of learning.

I was able to successfully use flask to create a handful of routes, but when I try to generate them dynamically I keep getting to an assertion error:
"AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: j_show_html"

To get around that, I tried dynamically creating python functions (which seems like a bad idea). What is a better way to dynamically create these date based pages?

Here is my python script:

```
from flask import render_template, Flask
import pandas
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
out_IP_address = "0.0.0.0"
out_port = 5000

fileLoc = "C:/"
fileName = "Rand_QA_Calls"
start_date = "2017-01-01"
out_date = []
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start='2017-01-01', end='2017-12-31').to_pydatetime()

for i in range(0,365):
    temp_date = datetime.strptime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(days=i)
    code = """
    def {0}():  
        report = pandas.read_excel('{1}'+"/"+'{2}'+"_"+'{3}'+"_"+'{3}'+".xlsx") 
        return render_template('view.html', 
        tables=[report.to_html(index=False)])""".format("j_show_html_"+str(i),fileLoc,fileName,temp_date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    print(code)
    @app.route("/"+temp_date.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    exec(eval(code))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=out_IP_address,port=out_port,debug=True)
```

And here is my HTML (utilizing jinja2):

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Simple tables</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
  <h1>Rand_QA_Calls</h1>
  {% for table in tables %}
    <h2>{{titles[loop.index]}}</h2>
    {{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And finally here is the CSS:

```
body            { font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;}
a, h1, h2       { color: #377ba8; }
h1, h2          { margin: 0; }
h1              { border-bottom: 2px solid #eee; }
h2              { font-size: 1.2em; }

table.dataframe, .dataframe th, .dataframe td {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C8C8C8;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

tr:nth-child(odd)       { background-color:#eee; }
tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color:#fff; }

tr:hover            { background-color: #ffff99;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I wasn't passing a variable through the route, but that made it much easier.

```
from flask import render_template, Flask
import pandas
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
#from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
import urllib2

app = Flask(__name__)
out_IP_address = "0.0.0.0"
out_port = 5000

fileLoc = "C:/"
fileName = "Rand_QA_Calls"
start_date = "2017-01-01"
out_date = []
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start='2017-01-01', end='2017-12-31').to_pydatetime()

@app.route("/tables/")
@app.route("/tables/<date>")
def j_show_html(date):
    report = pandas.read_excel(fileLoc+"/"+fileName+"_"+date+"_"+date+".xlsx")
    return render_template('view.html',
    tables=[report.to_html(index=False)],
    titles = ['na'],
    labels = urllib2.unquote(date.encode('ascii','ignore')))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=out_IP_address,port=out_port,debug=True)
```